# Get yarn applicationId from a submitted mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I need to be able to get the yarn applicationId from a mapreduce job. I can't find any API to do that. An Example of my mapreduce job:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
job.submit();
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Is there an API similar to `job.getJobId` to retrieve the yarn applicationId? I know about `yarn application -list` command but I need to be able to know the applicationId in my program through some kind of API. It looks like jobId is same as applicationId execpt for the prefix ('job' vs 'application') which I could parse but I am hoping there is something from the API I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up parsing the jobId, removing 'job' prefix and adding 'application' prefix as it appears applicationId is not exposed for mapreduce job and it is basically the same id as jobId with different prefix. It's a hacky approach but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
job.getJobID().appendTo(new StringBuilder("application"))
```

If you see the JobID class, there they are passing "JOB" as an argument which can be replaced by application in this case.

This will give the application id.